# How to iterate list of objects in terraform locals

Tags: list, for-loop, object, foreach, terraform

Basically, we are trying to create cloudwatch dashboards using terraform 0.13.5 and our requirement is to pass the 2 variable to widget block i.e. ${function_name} and ${title}.This will be passed as object variable.

Error : Invalid template interpolation value
Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

here is the code:

```
locals{
    lambda = [
        {
            function_name = "lambda1"
            title = "Error"
        },
        {
            function_name = "lambda1"
            title = "Error1"  
        }
    ]
    widget_defination = <<EOT
    %{ for function_name , title in local.lambda}
    [
    {
      "type": "metric",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 12,
      "height": 6,
      "properties": {
        "metrics": [
          [
            "AWS/EC2",
            "CPUUtilization",
            "FunctionName",
            "${funtion_name}"
          ]
        ],
        "period": 300,
        "stat": "Average",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "title": "${title}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
%{endfor }
EOT
}
```

Comment: I was assigned to review / improve your question but I am afraid we are going to have a disagreement here so I will try to give you an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha.

We need to call objects in widgets like -

${function_name.function_name} and
${function_name.title}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not the way to work with variables in terraform.
You have to declare the variables and type on its own file and assign their values in a different file or as a result of a resource creation.

You are talking about widgets so I'm not sure if you already know that because I've never used widgets before. But if you need some help ASAP I don't mind to try..

> variables.tf

```json
variable "project_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "vpc_id" {}
...
```

> terraform.tfvars

```json
project_name = "my-project"
vpc_id = "vpc-10101010"
...
```

The way you put that in a template is up to you.
I would suggest a simple approach like bash but IDK maybe the widgets are fun

And a little EDIT here because I just saw your "Gotcha" late.. yes, do not mix variables and strings.. you should vote for your own answer :D

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you as it was specific to my usecase here. just posted if someone is trying this way. :)